# How to add a uncommitted blank row in Datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working to fill datagridview manually. So there is no datasource or databindings.
I kept `AllowUserToAddRows` to `True` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` to `True`

**MY WORK AND CODE**

- I tweaked to work my datagridview as Enter key goes to next cell to the right and not down.

  ```
   Private WithEvents ec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
  ```

And,

```
   Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso DgvGrid.EditingControl IsNot Nothing Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End If
    Return Nothing
   End Function
```

Also,

```
    Private Sub dgvGrid_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DgvGrid.KeyDown
    Try
        Dim iCol = DgvGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Dim iRow = DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Return
                e.Handled = True
                If iCol = DgvGrid.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    If DgvGrid.Rows(iRow).Cells("TCODE").Value = "" Then
                        MessageBox.Show("ENTER DETAILS AGAIN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                        DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid("TREATMENT", iRow)
                    Else
                        DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid("TREATMENT", iRow + 1)
                    End If
                Else
                    If iCol = 2 Then '#TREATMENT
                        If DgvGrid.Rows(iRow).Cells("TCODE").Value = "" Then
                            'CalculateData
                        Else
                            DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid(iCol + 1, iRow)
                        End If
                    ElseIf iRow = DgvGrid.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        DgvGrid.Rows.Add() '------------- ISSUE IS HERE
                        'DgvGrid.BeginEdit(True)
                    Else
                        DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid(iCol + 1, iRow)
                    End If
                End If
        End Select

        If e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
            If DgvGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0 Then
                DgvGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex1 As System.InvalidOperationException
        MessageBox.Show("CANNOT DELETE LAST ROW.", "BONNY SOFTWARE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("TAKE A PICTURE" & Environment.NewLine & "ERROR : " & ex.Message, "BONNY SOFTWARE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
   End Sub
```

Last,

```
    Private Sub ec_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles ec.PreviewKeyDown
    Try
        Dim iCol = DgvGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Dim iRow = DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Return
                e.Handled = True
                If iCol = DgvGrid.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    If DgvGrid.Rows(iRow).Cells("TCODE").Value = "" Then
                        MessageBox.Show("ENTER DETAILS AGAIN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                        DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid("TREATMENT", iRow)
                    Else
                        DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid("TREATMENT", iRow + 1)
                    End If
                Else
                    If iCol = 2 Then '#TREATMENT
                        If DgvGrid.Rows(iRow).Cells("TCODE").Value = "" Then
                            'CalculateData
                        Else
                            DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid(iCol + 1, iRow)
                        End If
                    ElseIf iRow = DgvGrid.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        DgvGrid.Rows.Add() '------------- ISSUE IS HERE
                        'DgvGrid.BeginEdit(True)
                    Else
                        DgvGrid.CurrentCell = DgvGrid(iCol + 1, iRow)
                    End If
                End If
        End Select

        If e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
            If DgvGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0 Then
                DgvGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex1 As System.InvalidOperationException
        MessageBox.Show("CANNOT DELETE LAST ROW.", "BONNY SOFTWARE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("TAKE A PICTURE" & Environment.NewLine & "ERROR : " & ex.Message, "BONNY SOFTWARE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
   End Sub
```

Mind that Datagridview's `KeyDown` and `ec_PreviewKeyDown` event are the same as I want same effect when cellEdit is active.

**ISSUE**
When I am at last column of the last row and try to add a row with code `DgvGrid.Rows.Add()` then the row is added above or might be something else happens leaving the above row blank as shown in image below

[image: ISSUE IMAGE]

But If I edit cell and type something then a new uncommitted row is created automatically and it works fine when Enter/Return is pressed. Shown in Image Below

[image: IMAGE WITH REQD SOLUTION]

But even if the datagridviewCell is in EditMode, a new uncommitted row won't be generated. It generates only when I type something or change the value.

If I can only get the uncommitted row without editing will do my work.

Any other approach/suggestion is accepted. Thanks

Comment: Honestly I never understand why people are so intent on trying to do this sort of thing directly on DVGs.  Just bind it to a data table even if you don’t do anything with it, you can create the data table at runtime and makes all this type row handling infinitely easier

Comment: Ya but it's nothing with fetching data or I've tried that before. Damn it's complicated. Okay I try to explain you. User will only fil data. Its like user had to select from sort of data and that data is written in Dgv. Lets say this dgv is for product. User select a product in column 2 i.e "treatment" in my condition. When he selects a product the product's rate prints automatically in last 2 columns which are Product's rates. Datatable is best practice but not in this case.

Comment: I agree with Hursey, using a `DataSource` simplifies everything regardless if the user enters data into the grid or not. You state that… _”User select a product in column 2 i.e "treatment" in my condition. When he selects a product the product's rate prints automatically in last 2 columns which are Product's rates.”_ … ? … User selects a product in column 2…? How does the user “select” something? This implies the grid already has data? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: A data table is just a collection of data rows.  It’s not exclusively used for fetching data from databases so yeah it’s just as as useful in this context as anything else.  Really thought it doesn’t even need to be a data table, any collection of typed objects will make this so much easier.  Leave the data grid view for what is does best which is user interaction

Comment: @JohnG Na Datagridview does not have any data. The data is selected by a help form that I created. Help form has the list of datas loaded. User just selects from it and I get the data from there to here in datagrid

Comment: @Hursey You are correct but I don't need a datasource. I want user to write data. How can I use datatable in that? All the data will be selected by user.

Comment: Exactly the same way as if you had filled the data table from a data base.  There is zero difference.

Comment: @Hursey, The same way? I need to give user a GUI. Where can I get GUI for a datatable with validation. The only GUI to fill data in a tabular form is Datagridview. I can fill datatable from Datagridview or vice versa but how can I provide a GUI to the user to fill data???

Comment: You could make a `DataTable` to HOLD the data. The table can be “empty” but has defined columns. Then if you use it as `DataSource` to the grid. The you can take the data from the other form the user picks from and add a new row to the `DataTable`. Also, if the user types data into a cell in the grid… it will also put this data into the `DataTable`. The `DataTable` HOLDS the data, the grid simply DISPLAYS it.

Comment: Well honestly, you said any other approach or suggestion is appreciated in your question, I’m just suggesting a different approach.  If you don’t see it working in your situation you’re free to disregard it.  Obviously I’m not understanding the need for such complexity

Comment: @Hursey Thank You so much for your help. But for a moment think of excel. There is a sheet and count that sheet as a datagridview. I can format cells to checkbox, combobox, etc so when user enters data he faces the validation and formatting. The same way I need datagridview here. Yes I am going to use datatable back to store data for calculations and insert data in database but I have to give user something to fill data into. Yes this is complex or maybe my fault I can't explain you properly.

Comment: @JohnG **if the user types data into a cell in the grid** -Thats it. Thats why I need Datagrid. And I am just asking that I want a new row when user clicks Enter but what I wrote yeilds to different result. Its just winform GUI based solution that I need

Comment: I am sorry if I am not making this clear. It is true that … _”if the user types data into a cell in the grid -Thats it. Thats why I need Datagrid.”_ … we are NOT implying that you DO NOT use grid. We are simply saying that if you “bind” the grid to some `DataSource` then it will make things easier in many ways. How you want the GUI to work by moving the selection right on enter has nothing to do with "how" the data is stored in the grid. Nor is adding a row, just add it to the table.

Comment: @JohnG Enter keypress does'nt just enter data. There are validations too. For an instance you think that I just wanna insert data in Datagridview from user only and no data coming from Database or any selection.

Comment: Again, I was only trying to help. It appears my comments have suggested something that has given you a negative impression of their purpose. I am sorry if I suggested that the user use the “Tab” key… it was just a question. Please know that if you have taken offense to any of comments I sincerely apologize. I meant nothing more than to suggest some possibly better option. I am aware now that there is more to this than I am aware of and I am sorry for missing the obvious. Good Luck.

Comment: @JohnG You spared your precious time for me. Thank You so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my small tests, one thing I am curious about is “how” the row was added into the grid in the first picture?...

[image]

Specifically, the top first grid… it looks odd in one sense that… *“where is the new row?”* … Taking into account that the grids `AllowUserToAdd` rows property is set to `true`… then the user clearly did not “type” the data into the grid.

So, we can only assume the data was programmatically added to the grid? And… the ONLY way I could get the grid to look as shown at the top, is if I programmatically added the data to the individual cells in the grids “new” and only row… something like…

```
DgvGrid.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = “SomeValue”….
```

This may well display in the last row as we can see, however, there is a problem with manually adding the data to the grids “NEW” row … And in a nut shell… you don’t want to do that.

You can see from your example, that if you “add” a new row sometime “AFTER” we added the data to the “new” row, then, that row with the data we previously added is STILL in the grids “new” row… and below the row that was just added… as your picture shows.

Without getting technical, the grids “NEW” row is a “special” row and is not really a row you want to add data to programmatically. Example; if you type a single character into a cell in the last “new” row of a grid… then you will notice that as soon as you type a single character into a cell, then the grid “automatically creates” a new row and the row you just typed into is no longer the “new” row. When your code adds the data manually to the “new” row, the grid does not get triggered to create a “new” row. That is what YOUR code needs to do… i.e., add a new row.

Basically, the code that is adding the data to the grid … is doing it wrong. Whatever that code does, it is clear that it should ADD a new row first as opposed to programmatically adding the data to the grids “new” row.

---

In addition, I have seen this before such that you want to change the behavior of the grid’s selection to move right as opposed to down when the user presses the “Enter” key. And I will not deny, that it is a little trickier than it may appear. The code below moves the selection right and adds a new row if needed as shown below in action.

[image]

Below is my approach to this such that if the user presses the “Enter” key, that the selection will move to the cell on the right as opposed to down, IN addition… if the selection is in the LAST cell of the LAST “new” row, regardless if the cell is in edit mode or not, and the user presses the “Enter” key, then, a new row is created. I would not necessarily do this as the code will keep adding “empty” rows if the user repeatedly presses the enter key on the last “new” row. But I am guessing you want this behavior.

To simplify things, I used `SendKeys` to “move” the selection as opposed to setting the grids `CurrentCell` row and column indexes. In other words, we already know that if the user presses the “Enter” key then the grid’s “normal” selection/CurrentCell will move “DOWN” to the next cell. So, we simply need to send a “Tab” key, then an “UP” arrow key to get the selection where we want on the right.

Obviously, we need to check for boundary issues like the last column and last “new” row. In the case of the last column, the grid’s selection would simply move down and we only need to send the “HOME” key to get the selection to the first cell on that row.

If the selection is on the last “new” row AND last column, then we can ASSUME that there is NO data in any of the cells on that row… if there was data that the user typed into a cell on that row, then this row would NOT be the last row. So, the user would have to of pressed the “Enter” key multiple times WITHOUT typing any text into any of the cells… Or as you are doing… add the data to the “new” row programmatically. We will assume that the code is not doing this as it currently does and instead “adds” the row properly as it should. Otherwise, the new row will be on top as you show.

SO given this and to simplify the code, we will make a method that moves the selection to the cell on the right when the user presses the “Enter” key.

This method will be called by BOTH the GRIDS `KeyDown` event when a cell is NOT in “edit mode” and the `TextBox` cells `PreviewKeyDown` event when a cell IS in “edit mode.” This method will assume ONE thing only… The user just pressed the ENTER key. It is not important if a cell was in edit mode or not.

This `MoveGridSelection` method may look something like below with a walkthrough after.

```
Private Sub MoveGridSelection()
  If DgvGrid.CurrentCell IsNot Nothing Then
    If (DgvGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex < DgvGrid.Columns.Count - 1) Then
      If (Not (DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex = DgvGrid.NewRowIndex)) Then
        SendKeys.Send("{Up}")
      End If
      SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
    Else  ' current cell is LAST column
      If (DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex = DgvGrid.NewRowIndex) Then
        ' last cell on last 'new' row - do nothing and stay there
        '   Or set the selection back to the top
        '   Or add a New row as below ..? Not a good idea IMO
        DgvGrid.Rows.Add()
      End If
      SendKeys.Send("{Home}")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Walkthrough: If the grids `CurrentCell` column index is less than the number of columns, then… typically we could send a “Tab” and “UP” key to move right… UNLESS the cell is in the last “new” row… in which case we just want to send the “Tab” key to move right and do not send the “UP” key. So, we check if the row is NOT the “new” row, then we send the additional “UP” key.

If the grids `CurrentCell` column index IS the last column when the user presses the enter key, then the grid’s selection will move “DOWN” so we only need to send the “HOME” key to move the selection to the first cell in that row… UNLESS the selection is already on the last “new” row. In that case we have to make a decision, we could move the selection to the top left or do nothing OR add a new row. In this case the code adds a new row as I assume this is what you are wanting.

So again, we check if the row is the last “new” row and if it IS, we add a new row to the grid. After the row is added we send the “HOME” key to set the selection as the first cell in the “new” row.

We will be able to use this method in a couple of places using a couple of the grid events. Below is a brief summary of the grid events we will use and why we need to use them.

First is the GRID’s “KeyDown” event. This event is specifically for when a cell is NOT in “edit mode” and the user presses the “Enter” key.

```
Private Sub DgvGrid_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DgvGrid.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    MoveGridSelection()
  Else
    If e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
      DeleteCurrentRow()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Next, we need to capture when the “Enter” key is pressed and a cell IS in “edit mode.” As I am confident you are already aware... the grids `KeyDown` event will NOT fire when the user “edits” a cell and this makes sense in that the grid’s editor is capturing the keys for the cell.

Typically, we would use the grids `EditingControlShowing` event to help. When it fires, a cell is going into “edit mode.” We could cast the grids cell to a generic `TextBox` and then subscribe to that text boxes `KeyDown` event. This is how one would prevent the user from typing alpha characters into a cell that is numeric. Unfortunately, even in that case the `KeyDown` event will NOT fire if the “Enter” key is pressed. Fortunately, the `TextBoxes` `PreviewKeyDown` event WILL fire when the “Enter” key is pressed.

SO, we need the grids `EditingControlShowing` event to wire up this event when a cell goes into “edit mode.” To help, we will create a global `TextBox` variable called `EditedCell` and when a cell goes into “edit mode,” we will cast that cell to the global text box, wire up the text boxes `PreviewKeyDown` event and then wait until the user presses the “Enter” key. It may look something like…

```
Private WithEvents EditedCell As TextBox = Nothing


Private Sub DgvGrid_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DgvGrid.EditingControlShowing
  EditedCell = CType(e.Control, TextBox)
  RemoveHandler EditedCell.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf EditedCell_PreviewKeyDown
  AddHandler EditedCell.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf EditedCell_PreviewKeyDown
End Sub
```

Next, we need to implement this `EditedCell_PreviewKeyDown` event. Like the grids `KeyDown` event, we just need to check and see if the “Enter” key was pressed and if it was then we call our previous method to move the selection. In addition, since the user pressed the “Enter” key we also know that the cell will be ending its edit mode, so we no longer need the global text box or its event. So, we unwire the event and set the text box to `null`. If we do not do this, then the event may fire unexpectedly.

```
Private Sub EditedCell_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles EditedCell.PreviewKeyDown
  If (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter)) Then
    MoveGridSelection()
    RemoveHandler EditedCell.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf EditedCell_PreviewKeyDown
    EditedCell = Nothing
  Else
    If e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
      DeleteCurrentRow()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

This should be all we need to get the selection to move right instead of down.

And some missing code to delete the selected row if the Shift-Del keys are pressed.

```
Private Sub DeleteCurrentRow()
  If DgvGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0 Then
    If Not DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex = DgvGrid.NewRowIndex Then
      DgvGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(DgvGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Lastly, I have tested this, however, I am confident that I may have missed something obvious. So please let me know.